# Google App Script to read .XLS file from Google Drive

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets

I have a Microsoft .XLS/ .XLSX spreadsheets stored on the Google Drive ( not on Google Docs). Looking for a Google App Script to read spreadsheet from Google Drive without any upload/ conversion to the Google Doc.
I had written following function and try to open a excel using:

```
var xl = SpreadsheetApp.open(ImportXLSM.xls);
```

and than excel the sheet using:

```
xl.getSheetByName(sheet1);
```

but it shows an error : `Script function not found: doGet`

I am new to Google Script, please help!!!!

Comment: You can refer to this Question-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272308/script-function-not-found-doget

Comment: @Dave You are getting this error because you are trying to open excel sheet as a spredsheet using SpreadsheetApp.open(fileName), which is not allowed. You will have to convert your excel sheet into spreadsheet first.

Comment: But my boss's requirement is not to convert its format. Also the excel does have some macros implemented. I had already tied already by converting it to the Google Doc Spreadsheet and it works. But Since the requirement is to read the .xls/.xlsx read from the Google drive by Google sites.