# Publishing Google Apps Script to Chrome Webstore

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I published a script I wrote in Google Apps Scripts to Chrome Webstore. However, it is linked to a different script URL than the one I am using, so when I open the webpage it simply says: `Function doGet() not found`. However, when I open the correct URL including `/exec` in the browser it runs correctly.

Why is this happening?

And why is it only displaying "Visit website" and not "Add to chrome"?

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22627755):
saving and republishing your google script web app is not good enough. You need to save a new version and publish the new version to make sure your app gets updated properly.

Also additional answer from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22272680).

I would also recommend to read about [Apps Script Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) to get a gist of the foundation.